# How to create an index used by a WHERE extractValue(…) LIKE '…'?

Tags: oracle, xml

### Setup

Let's say you have a table with some XML data. For the sake of argument, say:

```
CREATE TABLE t_xml (xml XMLTYPE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO t_xml VALUES ('<name>Alice</name>');
INSERT INTO t_xml VALUES ('<name>Bob</name>');
INSERT INTO t_xml VALUES ('<name>Carol</name>');
INSERT INTO t_xml VALUES ('<name>Chuck</name>');
```

### A function index works with =

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t_xml WHERE lower(extractValue(xml, '/name')) = 'alice'
```

If I want this query to use an index, I can create a function index:

```
CREATE INDEX t_xml_f ON t_xml(lower(extractValue(xml, '/name')));
```

With this an explain plan tells me:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  
 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID T_XML"
  INDEX RANGE SCAN T_XML_F
```

So far so good.

### What index to use with LIKE?

But instead of `=`, what I really want is a `LIKE`. What index can I create so that the following query doesn't do a full table scan?

```
SELECT * FROM t_xml WHERE lower(extractValue(xml, '/name')) LIKE '%a%'
```

Now, Oracle won't use the above index with a `LIKE`, and this [for a reason](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1434815000346190059). If I wasn't using an `extractValue()`, I could use a text index. But I *am* using an `extractValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

A generic [`XMLIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDJECDA) should do the trick:

```
CREATE INDEX t_xml_x ON t_xml(xml) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLIndex;
```

Your explain plan will be:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  
 FILTER  
  TABLE ACCESS FULL T_XML
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID SYS15471_T_XML_X_PATH_TABLE
   INDEX RANGE SCAN SYS15471_T_XML_X_PIKEY_IX
```

You should be good with this, as long as your XPath expression doesn't use any of the [constructs not indexed by `XMLIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDCJDAA).